# Multiple DynamoDB tables with boto3: put item in table if person not exists in main table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

[DB schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jrxx.png)

I have got 3 DynamoDB tables linked through GraphQL and AppSync.
My api graph GetPerson return for skills a list of skills for that person scanning in Skills table. The same for Experience field.

Now I have to put new skills in skill table using a python script.
My problem is: how can I put a new skill in skill table when the person doesn't exist in main table? So I need to put the person in main table first, then put skill in skills table, if person doesn't exist. Instead if person exists I think I only need to do table.put_item()

Comment: Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options.  You could just use put_item() every time since it will create a new record if it doesn't exist or update the record if it does.  The issue is that writes are a lot more expensive than reads.

More cost effective would be to check if the Person exists before putting the skills item.